# Extracting value from a flat file using shell script

Tags: shell, grep, tail, flat-file, extract-value

I'm trying to extract the value present between brackets in the last row of a flat file e.g. " last_line (4) ". This is the last line and I want to extract 4 and store it in a variable. I have extracted the last row using `tail` command but now I am unable to extract the value between the brackets.

Kindly help.

Comment: try `| grep -Eo '\(.*\)'` and if you want to remove the brackets you can add a `| grep -Eo '[[:alnum:]]*'` at the end.

Comment: Is last row always contains numeric value ? if yes then simply use                     `grep -o '[0-9]*'`

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ cat input
first line
2nd line
last line (4) with some data

$ awk -F'[()]' 'END{print $2}' input
4
```

Comment: Right approach so `+1` but the last record read is only saved in the `END` section in some awks, to be portable you need to use `awk -F'[()]' '{s=$2} END{print s}' input`.

Answer (score 1):

```
l=$(tail -n1 filename); tmp=${l##*(}; tmp=${tmp%)*}; printf "tmp: %s\n" $tmp
```

**Output**

tmp: 4

Written in script format, you are using substring removal to trim everything up to the first `(` and everything after the last `)` from the last line, leaving only `4`:

```
l=$(tail -n1 filename)    ## get the last line
tmp=${l##*(}              ## trim to ( from left
tmp=${tmp%)*}             ## trim to ) from right
printf "tmp: %s\n" $tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

sed:

```
sed -n '${s/.*(//;s/).*//;p}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use this script.

In this script i saved the last line in a tmp file and at last removed it.
the number between the brackets() is in variable WORD

```
 #!/bin/ksh

if test "${DEBUG}" = "Y"
then

   set -vx

fi

tail -1 input>>tmp


WORD=`sed -n 's/.*(//;s/).*//;p' tmp`

echo $WORD

rm tmp
```